# how to get the position of the pattern in a string matched from the end

Tags: php

```
$a = "this is school of sachin";
$pattern = "sch";
```

I want to get the position of the pattern matched from the end. For example in this case, `sch` matches `school` -- so the position of the pattern should be 3, i.e. from the end:

as mentioned below the index for the word school are arranged in this manner,so if the match of `sch` is successful than the position from the end of the word which is getting matched(school) and to the start of the pattern(from the end) should be returned.

```
s c h o o l
5 4 3 2 1 0

^---^
```

*matched pattern.*

I have tried `strpos()` but could not make it to serve my purpose.

```
echo strpos($a, $pattern); // this is wrong
```

**The output of strpos() should be 3 according to my question.**

Comment: `so the position of the pattern should be 3` -- Could you explain?

Comment: @AmalMurali check my question.what i mean is if sch matches school than i want the index from the last of the matched pattern.

Comment: @AmalMurali i hope you understood my question?

Comment: You can get the length of the string with `strlen`. You have the position from `strpos`. You also have the length of the pattern. I guess you can finish the mathematical calculations needed to extract the number you need.

Comment: Do you mean that normally you would get `8`, because the matched `sch` starts at the 9th character of the string, and now you want `11` instead because that is the index of the first character _after_ the match?

Comment: your first part is correct but not the second part,i want o get the position from the end.

Comment: @kapa you are right but i guess whitespace will also get counted in strlen and its not the optimized way when the string is too big.

Comment: The end of the word that contains the pattern ?

Comment: @RishabhRaj: Sorry, but I don't quite get what you're trying to do. How did you get the position as `3`?

Comment: @RishabhRaj Sorry, this is not really a code writing service. What you need is not a simple task and trying a simple strpos does not really show effort to me. -1

Comment: @AmalMurali see the answer sharanaya dutta posted ,you might get an idea.

Comment: This part in your question confuses me: `I want to get the position of the pattern matched from the end. For example in this case, sch matches school -- so the position of the pattern should be 3, i.e. from the end:`-- Could you please update the question and explain in detail what you're trying to accomplish? That way, you'd get more accurate answers.

Comment: @Rishabh Raj, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20660449/1607528

Comment: @RishabhRaj: I think I've understood what you're trying to do. I've posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20660727/1438393) below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$a = "this is school of sachin";
$pattern = "sch";
$words = explode(" ", $a);
$pattern = strrev($pattern);
foreach($words as $word){
$pos = strpos(strrev($word), $pattern);
    if($pos !== false){
    print($pos);
    break;
    }
}
?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php
$a = "this is sachinùs school of sachin";
$pattern = "sach";
if(preg_match("/[^ [:punct:]]*".$pattern."([^ [:punct:]]*)/u", $a, $match)){
print(mb_strlen($match[1], "UTF-8"));
    if($pattern == $match[0]){
    print(" (full word)");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: is there no simpler approach?

Comment: @RishabhRaj I’ve updated my answer. I think the second approach is simple enough.

Comment: perfect,but will it work for non english characters? http://3v4l.org/OPeu8 here the string has got one dutch character and hence your code is not working

Comment: @RishabhRaj Now I’ve added Unicode support to my second approach.

Comment: sharanya:last qusetion what if i want to check whether full word exist in that string or not in case of non english character?

Comment: @RishabhRaj See the answer below, it tells if the found word is full or not

Answer (score 1):

Without the whole approach suggested by Sharanya

```
$haystack = 'this is a verygood school of sachin';
$pattern = 'sch';

$match = strstr($haystack, $pattern);

for ($i = 0;$i < strlen($match);$i++) {
    if ($match[$i] == ' ') {
        $match = substr($match, 0, $i);
        break;
   }
}
$result = strlen($match) - strlen($pattern);
echo $result;
```

Note that it will find the FIRST occurence starting from left, so for example 'schschool' would output 6.

Comment: What result do you expect to get from that example ?

Comment: I mean from the string 'this is a verygood school of sachin', what result should be right ? (Remind "sachin" does not match "sch")

Comment: the answer should be 3 in any case as long as the pattern is sch and the word to be matched is school

Comment: @RishabhRaj I edited my answer, look if it does what you desire. I remind, once again that it will look for the FIRST occurence from the LEFT

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE - This also, tells you if the found word is full word or not**
Take a look -  http://3v4l.org/i94Lr

```
  $pattern = "sch";
  $b = explode(' ','this is school of sachin');
  $b = array_reverse($b);
  for($i=0;$i < count($b);$i++){
     if(strpos($b[$i],$pattern) !== false){
       echo $i+1;
       $full = ', not a full word';
       if($b[$i] == $pattern){
         $full = ', full word';
       } 
       echo $full;
       break;
     }
  }
```

Comment: It wouldn't. Your code will output `13`, but the OP wants `3` instead.

Comment: I guess he wants the position of word instead

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression with [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`) to find the word that matches the supplied pattern and then capture everything after the pattern using a capturing group. Then, simply return the length of that string:

```
$a = "this is school of sachin";
if (preg_match('/\b(sch(\w+))\b/', $a, $matches)) {
    echo strlen($matches[2]); // => 3
}
```

If you also want to account for non-English characters, then you  can use the `u` modifier:

```
$a = "this is sachinùs school of sachin";
if (preg_match('/\b(sch(\w+))\b/u', $a, $matches)) {
    echo strlen($matches[2]); // => 3
}
```

Comment: @RishabhRaj: Glad to have been of help. Sidenote: If you want to also check if it's a full word, you can simply check if `$pattern == $matches[1]`. See [example](https://eval.in/80610).